# Having trouble deserializing a JSON string of Objects

Tags: apex, json, map, deserialize, httpresponse

I'm trying to handle a JSON response..the format it comes in is not the best but I can't change it..Ive used JSON2APEX and can access the object values individually but I need to loop through them

The JSON2APEX class goes like this

```
public class DataSource {


    public Data _PLU;
    public Data _1ST;
    public Data _VSL;
    public Data _ARC;
    public Data _ICN;
    public Data _REP;
    public Data _SNGLS;
    public Data _XAUR;
    public Data _DGD;

    public class Data {
        public String percentChange;
        public String baseVolume;
        public String quoteVolume;
    }


    public static DataSource parse(String json) {
        return (DataSource) System.JSON.deserialize(json,DataSource.class);
    }


}
```

so instead of this "DataSource._PLU.baseVolume" I want to do something like

```
for(DataSource o : Data){
    string s = o.baseVolume;
}
```

Any ideas?
ps I've tried `Map<string, Object> meta = (Map<string, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(data);`
but when I try to loop through the keyset I can get the values but not drill down to each attribute

ex.

```
for(String obj : meta.keyset()){
    system.debug("sample"+meta.get(obj).baseVolume;
}
```

I get a variable doesn't exist error for `baseVolume`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `JSON.deserializeUntyped(data)`, you need to perform type casting to tell the Apex compiler what kind of object you're working with or you'll get errors because the type `Object` has no property `baseVolume` (e.g.).

One way to accomplish this would be:

```
for (Object obj : meta.keyset()){
    Data d = (Map<String, Object>)meta.get(obj);

    System.debug(d.get('baseVolume'))
}
```

This converts the untyped Object instance into a Map, whose `get` method you can use to obtain properties. (Unfortunately, you can't cast directly to a `Data` instance from a Map; please pardon my oversight).

If you do want to work with class instances rather than untyped Maps, you could also deserialize into a `Map<String, Data>`, which would have a `keySet` you could then iterate over.

Comment: Is there an issue, @JPG?

Comment: Hi David, 
I've done what you suggested 
for (String key : meta.keyset()){
    Data d = (Data)meta.get(key);
    System.debug(d.baseVolume);
} 

but I'm receiving the following error System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,ANY> to responseAPI.Data
I've also tried to cast it into a custom object but get same error
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Apologies for the oversight; I've updated above.

Comment: Hi David,  I was able to get it to work with the following code...now the question is could I streamline this or is this acceptable using best practices?
`Map<string,Object> meta = (Map<string,Object>) 
 JSON.deserializeUntyped(rBody);      
       for(String s : meta.keySet()){
   
          Map<string,Object> markets =  (Map<string,Object>) meta.get(s);
           String high = (String)markets.get('high');
           String low  = (String)markets.get('low');
\\logic here
}`

Comment: Hey @JPG, best to post a follow-up question with some specifics - comment threads get unwieldy fast. At a glance, it looks fine, but you'll want some error handling in case you get back weird JSON.